# Silverlight programmatic access to Sony RZ30N Video Feed

Tags: silverlight, video, streaming, webcam

I would like to bypass the web-server functionality of a **Sony SNC-RZ30N** network attached web cam and display the video feed in a Silverlight application.

I can't seem to find any examples of interfacing with the camera programatically.

Any leads would be much appreciated.  Thx.

Update 09/09/2008: Found a good site with Javascript examples to control the camera, but still no means to embed the video in an iFrame or the like:

http://www2.zdo.com/archives/3-JavaScript-API-to-Control-SONY-SNC-RZ30N-Network-Camera.html

Doug

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the details of the Sony network camera and the server side software. But what do you mean by web-server functionality - is that the UI that get served up to the users in form of a HTML page? Or is it something more, like a server capturing the video stream and transcoding it?

I think the direction you need to take is to first find the URL end-point of your video stream. Since it's a network camera I assume the camera has a built in IP-stack/HTTP server serving up the video stream. Once you have that feed you probably have to transcode it into a video format consumable by Silverlight. There are multiple tools you can use, but for Silverlight the preferred tool Microsoft Expression Encoder. It supports live transcoding of webcam video streams. I think it supports both Direct Show devices as well as video streams.